# Как правильно оптимизировать запрос к базе данных в Laravel 2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как можно в этом случае улучшить запрос к бд в Laravel?

в репозитории есть такие два метода

```html
    public function getCountAdverts(): array
    {
        return [
            Advert::STATUS_PUBLISHED => $this->getCount(Advert::STATUS_PUBLISHED),
            Advert::STATUS_CLOSED => $this->getCount(Advert::STATUS_CLOSED),
            Advert::STATUS_NOT_PUBLISHED => $this->getCount(Advert::STATUS_NOT_PUBLISHED),
            Advert::STATUS_MODERATION => $this->getCount(Advert::STATUS_MODERATION),
        ];
    }

    private function getCount(string $status): int
    {
        return Advert::where('status', $status)->count();
    }
```

как то можно такой же массив получить только без 4 обращений к бд?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делаете один whereIn запрос со всеми нужными статусами, а потом пробегаетесь и делаете подсчёт в PHP по каждому. Либо можно через [CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789396/how-to-get-multiple-counts-with-one-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно помочь: [Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

```
$collection = DB::table('adverts')
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count, status'))
                    ->groupBy('status')
                    ->get();

$keyed = $collection->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [
        $item->status => $item->count
    ];
});

return $keyed->toArray();
```

---

Если проблема в том, что всё очень медленно, нужно сделать индекс по полю статус. Либо хранить количества в отдельной табличке и при каждом телодвижение их обновлять.. такое себе, конечно...